# BlazeDS Manually Set Cookie

Tags: java, blazeds

I'm new to Java. I'm writing an application to link to a vendors Flash site.  I have my BlazeDs based program talking to their site.  I'm running into a problem where a session cookie is not getting set.  The problem is that the host doesn't return it as a **"set-cookie"** header.

Their site returns the following cookieDirectives to set the SMSESSION cookie

```
cookieDirectives    
Externalized Object 
flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection
[0] String SMSESSION={CONTENT STRIPPED FOR CLARITY}; max-age=-1;path=/; domain=.-----.com
```

I can set the cookie in my amfConnection as follows:

```
amfConnection.addHttpRequestHeader("Cookie", resultString);
```

However, that only gives me the one cookie and there are several others I need.  The others have been set earlier by the host and are set using a **"Set-Cookie"** header.

How can I either add this cookie to the existing ones or  recover the existing cookies so I can manually add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing my approach.  Instead of relying on my amfConnection to handle the cookies I grab the session id using httpclient, store it in a variable, and then push my cookies to amfConnection.